# Is e^x of the same order of growth as e^(2x)?

Tags: big-o

Would they both fall under the case of 2^n (that is, the order of growth of exponential functions?)

Comment: Consider the substitution x' := 2x giving e^x'.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because you can write `e^(2x)` as `(e^2)^x` then you can see that `(e^2)` is a constant factor which does not influence the growth-class. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Exponential_time

Comment: Just to be clear: `2^n`, `e^n` and `e^(2n)` are all in `EXPTIME` (and `E`), but the latter two are not in `O(2^n)`.

Comment: @sepp2k Does that mean that none of them are big theta of one another? (since big theta implies both big O and big omega)